How can I prove that all eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm i$?
Let $n$ be an even positive integer. Suppose $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a skew-symmetric unitary matrix, show that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm i$ each with multiplicity equal to $n/2$.
From it being skew-symmetric I know that $tr(A)=0$ and from being unitary that $| \lambda|=1 $, however I am struggling to prove some "last" piece of information like "All eingenvalues are imaginary" to finish the proof. How can I finish the proof?

You mean skew-hermitian? The eigenvalues of a skew-hermitian matrix are purely imaginary.

If you do mean skew-symmetric, it's not true unless $A$ is assumed to have real entries.  Otherwise, note that
$iA$ satisfies the hypotheses whenever $A$ does, and its eigenvalues are $i$ times the eigenvalues of $A$.

The problem really says skew-symmetric. And I was wondering if $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ were a mistype too, but I prefer not jumping to conclusions and receive other people's insights first.

$$\langle Ax,x \rangle = (\lambda x)^H x = \bar{\lambda} x^H x$$
$$\langle Ax,x \rangle = (Ax)^H x = x^H A^H x  = x^H(-Ax) = -\lambda x^H x$$
Hence:
$ -\lambda =  \bar{\lambda} \implies \lambda$ is purely imaginray.
